# SongBeamer Print pdf

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, applications, pdf

I need export the songs of SongBeamer with the accords as PDF on an MacBook. On Windows I can press Print and then select pdf as print options. with the MacBook I can't do the same. I have add an printscreen of the program. Do someone know how to print as PDF in SongBeamer?
Thanks in advantage
[image]

Now after all the work. I will thank you all for the helping. I have contact the vendor. He have released a new version of SongBeamer just for this case. Here the Link: [Download (today is the: 06.01.2017)](http://www.songbeamer.de/bin/OSX/SongBeamer.dmg) Just in case please go to the website and watch out for a newer version. If there is one then download it. Probably it will be more stable.

Comment: You will get better answers by contacting the vendor directly (https://songbeamer.com/support.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whether I did something special, but if you change the name of the printer there is an option to print to PDF.

[image]

Comment: I havn't add any printer. 
The pdf printer isn't there as well.
Do you have a special pdf tool?

Comment: I have add a fixing in the description, I'm not a Stackexchange poweruser, but I think this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, because whoever coded it thought they knew better than Apple, so completely ignored the Mac-standard toolbox & wrote their own print dialog - & in the process forgot there's a reason to use standard toolboxes.

[image]

From Patrix's answer, it may be possible to add an Adobe pdf 'printer' from System Prefs > Printers & scanners.
Click the + sign at the bottom & see if you are offered one.

[image]

I think mine may have come from an old install of Adobe Acrobat which I no longer have. If so, maybe see if they do a free trial, which might just get you the PDF Printer as an add-on.
I found this [link to a free trial of Acrobat](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/print-to-pdf.html) which may offer the same thing as I have, though untested.

Comment: and what do you suggest to do?

Comment: First, complain at whoever wrote it, but in the meantime you may be able to get the same additional dialog as @Patrix - I'll add to the answer...

Comment: my problem is, there is no Option to get this additional dialog. I have no idea where he gets them.

Comment: Hey, i have installed the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and I cant add a pdf printer? there is nothing to add I can't find anything

Comment: It's back :-) But I don't have the "Adobe PDF" option in my Printer settings.

Comment: 'Reader' is not 'writer' - try the link I just added

Comment: @rikvola Please contact the vendor (they have both a support form and a user forum on their site). You paid for the software, they should support you as well here.

Comment: LOL. Your link points to software requiring "Apple System software 7.1" and delivered as a SEA file. Don't think this will work in macOS :-)

Comment: hahaha - sorry, i didn't check - updated to link for Acrobat DC free trial, which may offer the same thing. Confusion was it said 8.5.1, mine is 8 & quite old... so I *assumed* it was a later version :/

Comment: soo thanks, I don't know if i do something wrong, but now i have installed following programs: Acrobat Distiller, Adobe Acrobat, Some Launcher and Creative cloud. I tried you're first link, and it was broken. Now I don't find it anymore. I cannot set up the adobe printer as additional option. it is shown only if the program is programmed well in the "pdf" section wich isn't in SongBeamer. I have write to the vendor of this tool. It's really hard to do a so simple task.